# Difference between promise and deferred when wrapping your entire block of code in a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, deferred

With deferred (using your library of choice):

```
const deferred = library.defer();
if (condition) deferred.resolve('success');
else deferred.reject('fail');
deferred.promise.then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Just wrapping in a promise:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (condition) resolve('success');
  else reject('fail');
}).then((result) => console.log(result));
```

What's the difference between these two scenarios? Is the only real benefit that you don't have to wrap all your code in a promise? If that's the case what's the point of a deferred?

Comment: Deferreds are [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred), here's good read up on main reasons why it's better to not use them: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern .

Comment: @bardzusny: No, this has nothing to do with the [explicit promise construction antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A deferred is an object that has the `resolve` and `reject` method, allowing it's state to be changed. A promise doesn't.

As for generating promises in both ways, generally there shouldn't be any difference. I prefer the syntax of Promises since it wraps your logic in a function and avoids polluting the outer scope with variables, but that's about it.

Comment: `new Promise` will also cause the promise to reject if there is a synchronous error, whereas the function containing the deferred could _sometimes_ reject and _sometimes_ throw.

Comment: I thought of that but wasn't sure. Can you please give me a reference? I know it works in `then`s.

Comment: If you want specifics, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor step 10 would be the primary source.